# call to sprintf crashing in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I'm trying to call `sprintf` to format a string and store the result in a stack variable. However, my attempt is failing miserably and it crashes instantly.

```
sub esp, 0x100                                  ;Allocate 256 bytes on the stack.
push dword[RequestedFile]                       ;push string2
push dword[Host]                                ;push string1
push dword[GetHeader]                           ;push format   "String1: %s, String2: %s"
push dword[ebp - 0x04]                          ;push buffer/stack variable
call [sprintf]                                  ;store string in buffer
add esp, 0x10                                   ;restore stack

push dword[ebp - 0x04]                          ;push the stack variable.
push StringFormat                               ;push the format
call [printf]                                   ;print the new string.
add esp, 0x08                                   ;restore the stack

add esp, 0x100                                  ;destroy the stack variable.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where does it crash? Shouldn't your `add esp, 0x04` be `add esp, 0x08`? If you have access to a C compiler you might want to look at an equivalent example in C and see what it generates.

Comment: It crashes on the call to `sprintf` Yes you are correct it should be `0x08`. Fixed, but it still crashes on the call to `sprintf`. I tried gcc explorer: http://gcc.godbolt.org/ with the `-m32` flag, but I don't understand lea and the instructions it uses. I'd prefer to use `push`. It doesn't seem to call `sprintf` either.

Comment: `lea` is a really fundamental, important instruction. You should be familiar with it if you're planning to work with assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `[ebp-4]` as if it were a pointer to your buffer, when in fact it is just random memory garbage in the last 4 bytes of your buffer (assuming nothing else has been allocated from the stack yet). If you want to keep using `[ebp-4]` you will need to allocate that from the stack too and initialize it to the address. For example:

```
sub esp, 0x104                  ;Allocate 256 bytes buffer and 4 bytes pointer
mov dword[ebp - 0x04], esp      ;store address of buffer in local variable
push dword[RequestedFile]       ;push string2
push dword[Host]                ;push string1
push dword[GetHeader]           ;push format   "String1: %s, String2: %s"
push dword[ebp - 0x04]          ;push buffer/stack variable
call [sprintf]                  ;store string in buffer
add esp, 0x10                   ;restore stack

push dword[ebp - 0x04]          ;push the stack variable.
push StringFormat               ;push the format
call [printf]                   ;print the new string.
add esp, 0x08                   ;restore the stack

add esp, 0x104                  ;destroy the stack variables.
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'll +1 it though. It makes sense. Edit: Worked. Didn't change anything :S