# How to call sprintf() function in x86-32 bit?

Tags: c, x86

I am writing a function in C where I used sprintf() function and I have to rewrite this c code in x86-32 bit architecture. Everything else seems fairly straightforward except for calling this c function from assembly code. I found a few videos explaining writing printf() function but that does not help much because sprintf has three arguments and I have no idea where the third argument, buffer pointer should go. 
this is my sprintf in C:

```
sprintf(keyPtr + strlen(keyPtr),"%x", LFSR_STATE);
```

It is in a loop, so strlen(keyPtr) helps to append to the previously written data rather than to rewrite it.
I couldn't find any information relating to sprintf() function in Assembly and that's why I am asking it here. Can you put me in the right direction how I go about doing this?

I would appreciate if you could link to a manual which explains this if such thing exists.

Or do you think it will complicate the assembly program and I should avoid calling a C function from Assembly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [call to sprintf crashing in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462749/call-to-sprintf-crashing-in-assembly)

Comment: Do you know how to call *any* C function from assembler? If not then start with that, and then you will know how to call `sprintf` as well.

Comment: You can make your code simpler by using `keyPtr += sprintf(keyPtr , "%x", LFSR_STATE);` (and keep a copy of the pointer to the start somewhere else).  `sprintf` returns the number of bytes appended, not including the terminating `\0`, so this avoids needing to strlen in the loop.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes, one less function to call from Assembly.